# Joining to Active Directory Problem

Tags: active-directory

I have got some problem to join one computer to Domain. First I got this error Messages when try to join to DC

> Your Computer could not joined to the dc.. While processing a change to DNS host name for an object the service principle name values could not be kept in sync.

we have windows server 2003 AD and DHCP.it`s very interesting that I can join DC with this computer name without any problem on other computer in network!!!

I got this error too, What is this mean?!

> The Directory Service is Busy.

Answer (score 2):

> it`s very interesting that I can join
>   DC with this computer name without any
>   problem on other computer in
>   network!!!

If you already have a computer account on the domain by another name, I'm fairly certain you won't be able to join with a 2nd computer of the same name.  You may also want to research SIDs (Security ID) to make sure you're not trying to use two computers with matching SIDs on the same domain.

Comment: You are right, we deleted the computer name in AD before join to network